# Parsing SQL queries in python

Tags: python, sql, parsing

I need to built a mini-sql engine in python.So I require a sql-parser for it and I found out about python-sqlparse but am unable to understand how to extract column names or name of the table e.t.c from the SQL query.Can someone help me regarding this matter.

Comment: without a specific problem, no one can help you here.

Answer (score 8):

Lets check python sqlparse documentation: [Documentation - getting started](https://sqlparse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro/#getting-started)

You can see there example how parse sql. This is what is there:

**1. First you need parse sql statement with parse method:**

```
sql = 'select * from "someschema"."mytable" where id = 1'
parsed = sqlparse.parse(sql)
```

**2. Now you need now get Statement object from parsed:**

```
stmt = parsed[0]
    '''(<DML 'select' at 0x9b63c34>,
 <Whitespace ' ' at 0x9b63e8c>,
 <Operator '*' at 0x9b63e64>,
 <Whitespace ' ' at 0x9b63c5c>,
 <Keyword 'from' at 0x9b63c84>,
 <Whitespace ' ' at 0x9b63cd4>,
 <Identifier '"somes...' at 0x9b5c62c>,
 <Whitespace ' ' at 0x9b63f04>,
 <Where 'where ...' at 0x9b5caac>)'''
```

**3. then you can read again parsed sql statement with str() method:**

```
#all sql statement
str(stmt)
#only parts of sql statements
str(stmt.tokens[-1])
#so the result of last str() method is 'where id = 1'
```

Result of `str(stmt.tokens[-1])` is then `'where id = 1'`

**If you want name of the table you just need write:**

```
str(stmt.tokens[-3])
#result "someschema"."mytable"
```

**If you need names of the columns you can call:**

```
str(stmt.tokens[2])
#result *, now it is operator * because there are not columns in this sql statements
```

Comment: Thanks I got it :)

Comment: `sqlparse.parse(sql)[0].get_name()` gives table name

Comment: I am trying to perform operation on CREATE statement, how can i find the name of all columns, i tried using str(stmt.tokens[2]) but it doesn't gives the column name.

Comment: Just trying to understand how is this better than string.split() ?