# How to write the python script for parsing this SQL query, essentially showing the Data Lineage?

Tags: python, mysql

Input SQL:

```
SELECT A.COL_1 , B.COL_1 , A.COL_2 FROM TB_A inner join TB_B on TB_A.COL2 = TB_B.COL3
```

Output of SQL should be:

```
Source Table:  
TB_A 
TB_B   
Mapping Of Column:  
TB_A -> COL_1  
TB_A -> COL_2 
TB_B -> COL_1
```

Comment: You need a formal SQL parser for this.

Comment: refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39289898/parsing-sql-queries-in-python).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Hi Tim, what does it mean by 'formal' SQL parser ? Isn't it possible to write a python script ? Thanks anyways