# How do I remove line breaks and only return characters between two substrings in a list?

Tags: python

If I have a string like:

```
query = """
SELECT
   alias.column_one,
   alias.column_two,
   alias.column_three
FROM
   table_name
"""
```

How do I just return the characters between "SELECT" and "FROM" in a list so I have a list like below which also accounts for line breaks:

```
columns = ['alias.column_one', 'alias.column_two', 'alias.column_three']
```

I've tried importing re but I'm still stuck

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592) Just running `import re` isn't going to do a whole lot...

Comment: Have you tried np.fromstring()? I think that is what you are looking for. np is Numpy

Comment: The answer from @Vineet appears to satisfy your question. But MattDMo points out that if your query looks any different, you might have issues. It'll take some learning, but the sqlparse module will get it done, https://stackoverflow.com/q/39289898/246801.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
query = """
SELECT
   alias.column_one,
   alias.column_two,
   alias.column_three
FROM
   table_name
"""

columns = query.split('\n') # split the string at every line break - '\n'
columns = [column.strip() for column in columns] # strip out the leading spaces

# take the slice of the list between 'SELECT' and 'FROM':
columns = columns[columns.index('SELECT')+1:columns.index('FROM')]
```

`columns.index('SELECT')` returns the index of the list `columns` at which the word 'SELECT' appears. `columns.index('FROM')` does the same thing for 'FROM'. By taking a slice of `columns` between the first index (plus 1 - because the slice returns the value AT the first index) and the second index, you get only those elements between 'SELECT' and 'FROM'.

Comment: This wouldn't work if the SQL query was all on one line.

Comment: @MattDMo, OP showed it on multiple lines. That solution satisfies OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need the substring between 'SELECT' and 'FROM'. You could try something like this:

```
>>> s
'\nSELECT\n   alias.column_one,\n   alias.column_two,\n   
alias.column_three\nFROM\n   table_name\n'

>>> print((s.split('SELECT'))[1].split('FROM')[0])

alias.column_one,
alias.column_two,
alias.column_three
```

Since the question mentioned to get characters. Considering you wanted the result as a list, you could extend the above as:

```
>>> t = (s.split('SELECT'))[1].split('FROM')[0]
>>> [x.strip() for x in t.split(',\n')]
['alias.column_one', 'alias.column_two', 'alias.column_three']
```

Answer (score 0):

use re to get the string between SELECT and FROM, in this case is

```
   alias.column_one,
   alias.column_two,
   alias.column_three
```

then split the string by ',' and use strip() method to remove blank characters at the beginning and end

```
import re

query = """
SELECT
   alias.column_one,
   alias.column_two,
   alias.column_three
FROM
   table_name
"""

pattern = re.compile(r'SELECT(?P<column>[\S\s]+?)FROM')
result = pattern.search(query)
columns = result.group('column').split(',')
columns = list(map(lambda x:x.strip(),columns))
print(columns)
```